# Field an UITextField when button tapped in a UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uitextfield

I gonna need your help to understand how to interact with an `UITextField` when button tapped.

This is my code in my `ViewController`:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    cell.addBookTapped.addTarget(self,action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)),for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.configureCell(with: books[indexPath.row], indexCell: indexPath.row )

    return cell
}

func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    let tag = sender.tag
    //Do Stuff
}
```

And in my `MyCollectionViewCell`, I configure all the button and `textView` and add tag in my button:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTextFielThatIWantToFieldWhenButtonTapped: UITextField!
```

In my `ViewController` inside my `func buttonTapped` I can't reach `myTextFielThatIWantToFieldWhenButtonTapped`.

How can write something in it when the button is tapped and be visible directly on the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to get your intended cell by calling `cellForItem` at an `indexPath` of your specific cell like below:  (for example your cell is in section 0 item 0 )

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? YourCustomCollectionViewCellClass
```

then you can access your variables inside your cell class :

```
cell.myTextFielThatIWantToFieldWhenButtonTapped
```